# fixing browsers vertical slider

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to keep the browsers vertical slider fixed to the side? Even when the page does't need to be actually scrolled (with low height). I'm using ajax to load few different contents into my container div and when the content is long the slider automatically appear and the page adjust itself causing my page to move slightly and I want it still. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
body {overflow-y:scroll;}
```

should do it

Comment: you're welcome. :)  That's happened to me before, and that's the reason why I love OS.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you: overflow property

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: apparently w3schools is unreliable. use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow instead

Comment: I can view w3schools correclty